# How to replace a specific href link using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, href

I'll try again with this as I'm not sure the last time I put a very clear question... I have a page that has a lot of linked images. I would like to change just one of the image links (it's the logo) using javascript. I can not directly edit the "body" html, but can put js in the "head" region.

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="ctl00">
  <h1 class="logo">
  <a href="http://www.store.domain.co.nz" title="Menswear"><img src="/user/files/logo.png title="Menswear" alt="Menswear"></a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

and I want to change the html to:

```
<div id="ctl00">
    <h1 class="logo">
<a href="http://www.domain.co.nz" title="Menswear"><img src="/user/files/logo.png title="Menswear" alt="Menswear"></a>
</h1>
</div>
```

Basically I want to remove the ".store" from the URL, but only this instance, not all URLs on the page.

Answer (score 8):

Check the DOM functions:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
for (i=0;i<x.length;++i) {
  if (x[i].getAttribute("href") == "http://www.this.link.co.nz") {
    x[i].setAttribute("href", "http://www.that.link.co.nz")
    x[i].setAttribute("title", "that link")
    x[i].replaceChild(
      document.createTextNode(
        "changed img:filename.jpg"
      ),
      x[i].firstChild
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="http://www.this.link.co.nz" title="this link">
    img:filename.jpg
</a>
</p>
<p><a href="http://www.this.link.co.nz" title="this link">
    img:filename.jpg
</a>
</p>
```

sets `x` to an array containing all **a** elements.

Comment: Thank you... Hmm this code would replace all instances of http://www.this.link.co.nz wouldnt it?  I only want it to replace the instance of the one link of the image (there are other instances of http://www.this.link.co.nz in the menu and I don't want to change them)

Comment: I understood your question that you wanted to replace all hrefs with the same target. You can use `getElementsByTagName` as well as `querySelectorAll` on elements too, to select only nodes from a subtree of your document. To learn about this study the Document and Element IDLs and descriptions in http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document. The querySelector functions are part of an extension api.

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question... so please bare with me and let me rephrase...

Comment: As there are multiple instances of the link and I only want to change the instance that is an image link I would like to find and replace the html string <a href="http://www.this.link.co.nz" title="this link"><img src="/filename.jpg"></a> with <a href="http://www.that.link.co.nz" title="that link"><img src="/filename.jpg"></a> using javascript.  I'm new to Javascript so your 2nd reply was a bit above my knowledge level.

Comment: First, it takes some time to study the IDLs but it helps in the end. You cannot search for text, but if you know about your document structure you can check the children of the `x[i]` in the loop (`x[i].firstChild.tagName=="img"`) for example. But be you need to check if there is a firstChild at all, or the javascript will produce errors. Just try these functions and get used to a javascript console, such as the one in google-chrome.

Answer (score 6):

One way could be is to use the href value to find the anchor

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="http://www.this.link.co.nz"]');
if (a) {
  a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.that.link.co.nz')
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.this.link.co.nz" title="this link">
  <img src="/filename.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: How do you setup this code snippet? Use querySelectorAll to return all matching elements. I still prefer working with elements and attributes though.